# Cant drop partition from header table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, partitioning

We have a header table which has a primary key and a detail table which references the header table (Foreign key). Both the header and detail tables are monthly partitioned. These tables contain 5 years of data, so when a new month comes the data for the first partition is deleted and so on. So that always only 5 years of data is maintained.

The problem that we are facing is while dropping the partition from the header we are getting the following error:

```
ORA-02266: unique/primary keys in table referenced by enabled foreign keys
ORA-06512: at "SCH_TEST.DROP_PARTITION", line 51
ORA-06512: at line 16 (DBD ERROR: OCIStmtExecute)
```

We have deleted the referencing data from the detail table, still the above error is occuring.

One way for solving this error is to disable the constraint, drop the partition and then enable the constraint. Is there any other approach/solution for this issue.

Database is Oracle 11G.

***Edit 1:*** I'm able to drop the partition from header table if i delete the data in the partition first and then drop it. Any idea how this works?

Comment: Looks like you have hit a bit of a limitation. There is a bit of a work around here which may or may not help you - http://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2006/12/10/drop-parent-partition/

Comment: Thanks Stephen. Its not working. Is there any limitation that we cant do this in 11g?

Comment: Not sure - If you can post up some DDL to create a test case that produces your problem I will have a play around if I get some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose "disable the reference constraint and then drop the partition" approach, as i did not find any other solution for this issue.

Posting this information here and accepting it as answer so that it may help others who search for the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle 11g introduced partition by reference for this. Are you using reference partitioning? If not you need to change your partitioning scheme.

Comment: Thanks steve. No, i'm not using reference partition